# Prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{k^{\frac34}}{(1-k^2)^\frac38} K(k)\text{d}k=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, dirichlet-series

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7081v1) mentioned a proposition:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{k^{\frac34}}{(1-k^2)^\frac38}
K(k)\text{d}k=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }.
$$
Its equivalent is
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\vartheta_2(q)^3\vartheta_4(q)^2
\sqrt{\vartheta_2(q)\vartheta_4(q)}\text{d}x
=\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }.
$$
I think that there is a $L$-series satisfying
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\vartheta_2(q)^3\vartheta_4(q)^2
\sqrt{\vartheta_2(q)\vartheta_4(q)}\text{d}x
=L_f(s)\Gamma(s)\times\text{other components}.
$$

Comment: In other words, the problme is to show that
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{8}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{8}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{8};1,\frac{3}{2};1\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know some similar hypergeometric series, like ${}_3F_2\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac18;1,\frac98;1\right)=\frac{\left ( 3+\sqrt{2}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2
\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{96\pi^2\sqrt{2} }$ and ,${}_3F_2\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac38;1,\frac{11}{8};1\right)=\frac{\left ( 3-\sqrt{2}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2
\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{32\pi^2\sqrt{2} }.$

Comment: I worked crazy and nothing came ! Cheers :-)

Comment: [Where is an error?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%5E%283%2F4%29%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29%5E%283%2F8%29+EllipticK%28x%29+dx)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Input `EllipticK[x^2]` instead

Comment: @SetnessRamesory This is your typo too)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov There's no typo. WA's definition differs from here $K(k)=K(\sqrt{k^2})=$`EllipticK[k^2]`.

Comment: It is also equal to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{k^{3/4}}{k^2+1}K(ki)dk$.

Comment: What have you calculated ? Read your last comment. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have calculated that:$$_3F_2(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{7}{8};1,\frac{3}{2};1) = 1 + \sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3 2^{5n}}\Pi_{k=1}^{n}(8k-1))$$ and $$\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})\Gamma(\frac{7}{8}) = \frac{2^{-\frac{7}{4}}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}K(3-2\sqrt{2})}$$I don't know if this is of any help or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months later, I finally find a self-contained proof(which do lead to a general expression). We have for $\Re(s)\in(0,2)$,
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^{s-1}K(x)\text{d}x
=\frac{\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right ) }{\pi}
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}2 \right )^2}{\Gamma(\frac{s+1}2)^2}
\int_{0}^{1}  x^{-s+1}(1-x^2)^{s/2-1/2}K(x)\text{d}x.
$$
Substituting $s=1/4$ and as a matter of fact that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^{-3/4}K(x)\text{d}x=\frac{\left ( 3+\sqrt{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{
48\pi\sqrt{2} },
$$
gives
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{\frac34}}{(1-x^2)^{\frac38}}K(x)\text{d}x
=\frac{\pi^2}{12}(2+3\sqrt{2})\sin\left(\frac\pi{8}\right),
$$
with
$$
(2+3\sqrt{2})\sin\left(\frac\pi{8}\right)=\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }.
$$
A related one:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{\frac14}}{(1-x^2)^{\frac18}}K(x)\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\sqrt{5-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }.
$$

Comment: This question is trivial if you know $${}_3F_2\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac18;1,\frac98;1\right)=\frac{\left ( 3+\sqrt{2}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2 \Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{96\pi^2\sqrt{2} }$$ i,e, $\int_0^1 x^{-3/4} K(x) dx$. Because it's obviously related to the one in question by standard $_3F_2$ transformation.

Comment: @pisco does your coefficient-comparing method applicable to series with factor $(\frac12)_n^2/(1)_n^2$?

Comment: It depends on what you want to prove precisely.

Comment: @pisco Just for curiosity. I still have obstacles dealing with extremely complicated computations(that should be done by computers). Could you share one?

Comment: then learn a bit about programing. I use Mathematica most of the time for complicated computations.

Comment: @pisco frankly, I once used some programmes(such as your integrating), but my current conditions are not really good. If any inconvenience, I am quite sorry for that.

Comment: @pisco of course some of them aren't, like a obvious one $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^3}{(1)_n^3} 
\frac{6n+1}{2^{2n}}\left ( H_{2n}-H_n \right ) 
=\frac{16\ln(2)}{3\pi}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{2^{8/3}\pi^4}$.

Comment: I believe if you uses certain software to aid those heavy computations, then you will definitely discover more amazing results.

Comment: @pisco What is FL recurrence relation of $\frac{K(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$? Or are there any methods which can judge the complexity of recurrence relations when $f(x)$ is given(without explicit computations)?

Comment: If $f(n) = \int_0^1 K(\sqrt{x})/\sqrt{x} P_n(2x-1)dx$, then $$-(2 n+3) \left(2 n^2+6 n+5\right) f(n+1)-2 (n+1)^3 f(n)-2 (n+2)^3 f(n+2) + 6 + 4n = 0$$ this recurrence has no hypergeometric solution. Regarding your second question, the answer is no, one always needs to do some computations.

Comment: @pisco Do you have any WZ identities which can be exploited to accelerate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^3 }{(1)_n^3}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2j+1)^2} 
=\frac{\left ( \pi^2-8G \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{32\pi^3}?$

Comment: Very likely yes, but I haven't done any concrete computation.

Comment: @pisco any idea with $\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,1;\frac34,\frac34;-\frac18 \right )
=\frac23+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}{3\sqrt{\pi} }?$

Comment: probably do-able, you can ask a new question if you want.

Comment: @pisco https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795746/

Comment: @pisco Do you have any insights into the connection between $K(k)$ integrals and MZVs? I could only found simple(and ugly) ones like$$\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{(2k^2-1)K(k)^2\arctan\left ( \frac{K^\prime(k)}{K(k)}  \right ) }{
\sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k
=-4\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac12 \right ) 
-\frac72\zeta(3)\ln(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln(2)^2-\frac{1}{6}\ln(2)^4+\frac{151}{2880}\pi^4.$$

Comment: It could be seen as a generalization to $\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{\arctan\left ( \frac{K^\prime(k)}{K(k)}  \right ) }{
\sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$