# Prove $\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,1;\frac34,\frac34;-\frac18 \right ) =\frac23+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}{3\sqrt{\pi} }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

With some experiments, I discover an identity, which eventually evaluates to
$$
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,1;\frac34,\frac34;-\frac18 \right )
=\frac23+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}{3\sqrt{\pi} }.
$$
This is special for the factor $-1/8$ and its simple result. I hope that there exist some ways we could attack it, and thank for your creative efforts.

Comment: At functions.wolfram.com I found this formula $${}_3F_2\left(a, 1 - a, 3 a - 1; 2 a, a + \frac12; -\frac18\right) =
\frac{ 2^{3 a - 3}}{\pi \Gamma\left(3 a/2\right)^2}
 \Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 \Gamma\left(a + \frac12 \right)^2$$ Maybe it is related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can give a very short and elementary proof using [WZ-pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair).

We have the following analytic fact: if $F,G$ satisfy $$\tag{WZ}F(n+1,k) - F(n,k) = G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$$ and moreover

- $\lim_{n\to\infty} G(n,k) = 0$ for each $k\geq 0$
- $\sum_{k\geq 0}
     F(0,k)$ converges
- $\sum_{n\geq 0} G(n,0)$ converges

then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k\geq 0} F(n,k)$ exists and is finite, also
$$\tag{1}\sum_{k\geq 0} F(0,k) =  \sum_{n\geq 0} G(n,0) + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k\geq 0} F(n,k)$$

*Proof sketch:*         We apply $\sum_{n= 0}^{N-1} \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}$ on both sides of $(\text{WZ})$, giving
$$\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} (F(N,k)-F(0,k)) = \sum_{n= 0}^{N-1} (G(n,K) - G(n,0))$$
by our assumption, we can let $K\to \infty$ while fixing $N$, to obtain
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} F(N,k) - \sum_{k\geq 0} F(0,k) = -\sum_{n= 0}^{N-1} G(n,0)$$
then letting $N\to\infty$ proves the claim.

---

Now let $$F(n,k) = \frac{2^{-2 k-3 n-2} \Gamma (n+1) \Gamma \left(2 k+n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(k+n+\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma (k+n+1)}\quad G(n,k) = \frac{2(2 k+3 n+1)}{4 n+3}F(n,k)$$
one checks $(\text{WZ})$ is satisfied. All three bullets are also met, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k\geq 0} F(n,k) = 0$. Therefore we have $$\sum_{k\geq 0} F(0,k) = \sum_{n\geq 0} G(n,0)$$
explicitly:
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{2^{-2 k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{2 k}}{(4 k-1) \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_k (1)_k} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1/8)^n (2 n+1) (3 n+1) (1/2)_n^2}{(2 n-1) (4 n+3) (3/4)_n^2}$$

LHS can be summed using Gauss's $_2F_1$ theorem, giving $-\frac{\Gamma(3/4)^2}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$. The summand of RHS is

$$-\Delta_n\left(\frac{(-1/8)^n(4 n-1) (1/2)_n^2}{(2 n-1) (3/4)_n^2}\right)-\frac{3}{2}\frac{(-1/8)^n (1/2)_n^2}{(3/4)_n^2}$$

here $\Delta_n f(n) = f(n+1)-f(n)$. From this we can get the value of $\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1/8)^n (1/2)_n^2}{(3/4)_n^2}$, which is OP's $_3F_2$ series.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is added for details. And this is also the "solution" that how I came up with the Hypergeometric series. At the beginning, it's more than easy to check the branch property of $K(k)$ defined by $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2} }\text{d}t$, since it resembles functions like $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ . We have
$$
K(k_{\pm})=\frac1k\left [ K\left ( \frac1k \right ) \pm iK^\prime\left ( \frac1k \right ) \right ]
$$
when $\Re(k)>1.$ The simple formula leads to great achievements. By contour integrations, millions of new integrals are produced. Choosing $f(z)=\frac{K(z)}{\left ( 1+z^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-z^2} }$ and after some clear manipulations we could get
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)+K^\prime(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }
\text{d}k=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{16} 
\left ( \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{\pi}+\sqrt{\pi}   \right ).
$$
Then we do the following steps:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)+K^\prime(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }
\text{d}k&=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{16} 
\left ( \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{\pi}+\sqrt{\pi}   \right )\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }
\text{d}k+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }
\text{d}k+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)}{\left ( 2-k^2 \right ) \sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k\\
&=3\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(k)}{\left ( 1+k^2 \right )\left ( 2-k^2 \right )  \sqrt{1-k^2} }
\text{d}k\\
&=\frac34\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left (  \sqrt{x} \right )  }{\left ( 1+\frac{x}2(1-x)  \right )
\sqrt{x\left ( 1-x \right ) }  } \text{d}x\\
&=\frac34\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \int_{0}^{1}
x^{n-\frac12}(1-x)^{n-\frac12}K\left ( \sqrt{x}  \right ) \text{d}x\\
&=\frac34\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}{4\cdot2^{2n}} 
\frac{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac12 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( n+\frac34 \right )^2 }\\
&=\frac{3\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4}{32\pi} 
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,1;\frac34,\frac34;-\frac18 \right ).
\end{align}
Therefore by these equations we conclude that
$$
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,1;\frac34,\frac34;-\frac18 \right )
=\frac23+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2 }{3\sqrt{\pi} }.
$$
The process gives me some ideas, as stated following:

1. Our solution is highly relied on the unique symmetry of $K(k)$. It seems that generalizations are possible to certain $\,_2F_1$ but still there are some work needed doing.
2. Both the evaluation and result are surprisingly elegant in the form. I believe that some inside natures are going to be unearthed but so far effective efforts are not enough, and still confuse me.

Comment: can you expand on this step?  How do you evaluate $K(x^{1/2})$ as a series to get the factorial sum? I understand you are using the beta function.

Comment: @CarP24 expand $K$ using power series and use beta function to derive a $\,_3F_2$ for the integral. And it matches the form in the formula:https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/02/03/0004/.

Comment: I notice that $k(x^{1/2})$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind given by $2f1(1/2,1/2,1,k)$ Does the 3f2 series arise from the double integral? I know that the 3f2 hypergeometric function can be expressed as a double integral. Are you using this one? https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/01/01/0001/MainEq1.gif

Comment: @CarP24 They are analogous indeed. I changed the order of the summation and integration.